# SQL sum of different status within 24 hrs group by hours

Tags: sql, count

I am trying to sum status within 24 hour groups by hours. I have an order, order status and status table.

Order Table:

```
+---------+-------------------------+
| orderid | orderdate               |
+---------+-------------------------+
| 1       | 2015-09-16 00:04:19.100 |
| 2       | 2015-09-16 00:01:19.490 |
| 3       | 2015-09-16 00:02:33.733 |
| 4       | 2015-09-16 00:03:58.800 |
| 5       | 2015-09-16 00:01:16.020 |
| 6       | 2015-09-16 00:01:16.677 |
| 7       | 2015-09-16 00:02:06.920 |
+---------+-------------------------+
```

Order Status Table:

```
+---------+----------+
| orderid | statusid |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 11       | 
| 2       | 22       |
| 3       | 22       |
| 4       | 11       |
| 5       | 22       |
| 6       | 33       |
| 7       | 11       |
+---------+----------+
```

Status Table:

```
+----------+----------+
| statusid | status   |
+----------+----------+
| 11       | PVC      |
| 22       | CCC      |
| 33       | WWW      |
|          |          |
+----------+----------+
```

I am try to write SQL that display the count of the status within 24 hours for distinct orderids grouped by hour like below:

```
+------+-----+-----+-----+
| Hour | PVC | CCC | WWW |
+------+-----+-----+-----+
| 1    | 0   | 2   | 1   |
| 2    | 1   | 1   | 0   |
| 3    | 1   | 0   | 0   |
| 4    | 1   | 0   | 0   |
+------+-----+-----+-----+
```

This is my SQL so far. I am stuck trying to get the sum of each order status:

```
SELECT
    DATEPART(hour, o.orderdate) AS Hour,
    SUM( 
        CASE (
            SELECT stat.status 
            FROM Status stat, orderstatus os  
            WHERE stat.status IN ('PVC') AND os.orderid = o.id AND os.statusid = stat.id
        ) 
            WHEN 'PVC' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END 
    ) AS PVC,
    SUM(
        CASE (
            SELECT stat.status 
            FROM Status stat, orderstatus os 
            WHERE stat.status IN ('WWW') AND os.orderid = o.id AND os.statusid = stat.id
        ) 
          WHEN 'CCC' THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
        END 
    ) AS CCC,
    SUM( 
        CASE (
            SELECT stat.status 
            FROM Status stat, orderstatus os 
            WHERE stat.status IN ('CCC') AND os.orderid = o.id AND os.statusid = stat.id) 
            WHEN 'WWW' THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
        END 
    ) AS WWW 
FROM orders o 
WHERE o.orderdate BETWEEN DATEADD(d,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP 
GROUP BY DATEPART(hour, o.orderdate) 
ORDER BY DATEPART(hour, o.orderdate);
```

Comment: does your status table have an error... it has 11 3 times with different values.

Comment: I corrected that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go -- I'm ignoring the errors in your data since this will fail if the status table really had duplicate ids like in your example data.

```
SELECT hour, sum(PVC) as PVC, sum(CCC) as CCC, sum(WWW) as WWW
from (
  select datepart(hour,orderdate) as hour, 
        case when s.status = 'PVC' then 1 else 0 end as PVC,
        case when s.status = 'CCC' then 1 else 0 end as CCC,
        case when s.status = 'WWW' then 1 else 0 end as WWW
  from order o 
  join orderstatus os on o.orderid = os.orderid
  join status s on s.statusid = os.statusid
) sub
group by hour
```

Answer (score 0):

this should get you closer, then you have to pivot:

```
SELECT 
   DATEPART(HOUR,o.orderdate) AS orderDate_hour, 
   s.status,
   COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderid) AS count_orderID
 FROM  
     orders o INNER JOIN
     orderstatus os ON
     o.orderid = os.orderid INNER JOIN
     status s ON
     os.statusid = s.statusid
WHERE 
    o.orderdate >= DATEADD(d,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
GROUP BY 
    DATEPART(HOUR,o.orderdate) , s.status
ORDER BY 
    DATEPART(HOUR,o.orderdate)
```

---

try this for the pivot:

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    (SELECT 
       DATEPART(HOUR,o.orderdate) AS orderDate_hour, 
       s.status,
       COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderid) AS count_orderID
     FROM  
         orders o INNER JOIN
         orderstatus os ON
         o.orderid = os.orderid INNER JOIN
         status s ON
         os.statusid = s.statusid
    WHERE 
        o.orderdate >= DATEADD(d,-1,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
    GROUP BY 
        DATEPART(HOUR,o.orderdate) , s.status) s
PIVOT ( MAX(count_orderID) FOR status    IN ('pvc','ccc','www')) AS p
ORDER BY 
    orderDate_hour
```

Comment: I will try it out and let you know. Thank you so much for your time and consideration.

Comment: The sql doesn't run. status is a table name. Did you mean to have status listed in the select statement as a column?

SELECT 
   DATEPART(HOUR,o.orderdate) AS HOUR, 
   status,
   COUNT(DISTINCT o.orderid)
 FROM

Comment: the first sql?  or the pivot?  is it giving you an error?

Comment: is the field name in the order table date, like in your example, or orderdate, like in your SQL?

Comment: orderdate not date. Sorry about that. The sql doesn't return results only two headers: Hour and another column with no header name. There should be 4 columns Hour, PVC, CCC and WWW filled with the sum of status for the distinct rows within 24 hours...

Comment: does the first sql work?  that has to be tested before the pivot is applied.

Comment: I will try running both SQL again. I will let you know.

Comment: First sql runs fine. 2nd sql doesn't run i get an error: Incorrect syntax near 'pvc'